# Good way to hide drywall seam with painted drywall?

Tags: drywall

I have two pieces of painted drywall backed with a 2x2 piece of wood, covered with an oak board, as shown in the attached picture.
[image]

The drywall seam exists because my main water shutoff is behind this area and I wanted to maintain easy access to the area. Is there a way I can hold the drywall seam in place (not taping, mudding and standing) that will hold the board in place without looking too terrible?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: naw i dont think so. build it out of wood and put the join the the conner

Comment: I don't understand the question. How does the drywall hold the board? What do you mean by "hold the seam in place"? Do you mean "hold the removable panel in place"? Please edit your post to clarify. a photo with a little more context would also help.

Comment: You could use a t-strip glued to one side, preferably the side that comes off. These are used a lot in older manufactured homes, even newer ones use them in closets. They join to panels together. This way they don't have to tape and texture. The panels are pre made and a spacer/trim piece is put between.